# Как происходит выгрузка фоновых активити?

Tags: android

С программированием под android только начинаю. Слышал, что в случае нехватки памяти, ОС может, как убивать приложения целиком, так и уничтожать только отдельные активити.
Где можно подробно почитать, как это происходит и как с этим жить?

Убиться может только активити целиком? То есть

- В активити вставлено несколько фрагментов. Возможен ли случай, что активити живо, но часть фрагментов убилась?
- А если объекты фрагментов не вставлены непосредственно в UI, но ссылки на них хранятся, чтобы вставить впоследствии. С ними ничего не должно случиться плохого?
- Или в свойстве класса активити хранится объект, который работает с неким View этой активити и оно хранится в его свойстве. Не может произойти так, что этот элемент будет перегенерирован и сохранённая ссылка будет указывать не на актуальный объект?
- Что с объектами не относящимися к UI? Они не могут быть уничтожены в какой-то момент по решению системы?

Comment: Поищите описание жизненного цикла активностей и фрагментов, к примеру на официальном сайте есть описание [раз](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle?hl=he) и [два](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/lifecycle?hl=he).